# Некорректно работает поле oveflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

Поставил на блоки `overlow:hidden` и `height:300px`. При наведении мышью на блок, он  увеличивает высоту до `100%`. И скрытая информация отображается, вот только при этом другие блоки смещаются, а нужно что бы скрытый блок всего лишь перекрывал часть другого блока, а не смещал. Как это исправить?

**ВНИМАНИЕ!** После того, как вы нажмете на "Выполнить код" разверните страницу во весь экран

```css
/* АДМИН ПАНЕЛЬ */
.admin-block { 
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.admin-block:hover { 
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
                0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    height: 100%;
}

.btn {
    width: 100%;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <div class="admin-block">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pXv6.png" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>ГАЛЕРЕЯ</h4>
                    <p>Редактирование раздела <br> "Галерея"</p>
                    <a class="btn" title="send" href="?option=edit_gallery">перейти</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="admin-block">
                <a href="?option=edit_users"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/571yh.png" alt=""></a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ</h4>
                    <p>Редактирование раздела <br> "Пользователи"</p>
                    <a class="btn" title="send" href="?option=edit_gallery">перейти</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div>
            <div class="admin-block">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajpmo.png" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>БИОГРАФИЯ</h4>
                    <p>Редактирование раздела <br> "Биография Федора М.М."</p>
                    <a class="btn" title="send" href="?option=edit_gallery">перейти</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="admin-block">
                <a href="?option=edit_statii"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzINl.png" alt=""></a>
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>СТАТЬИ</h4>
                    <p>Редактирование раздела <br> "Статьи"</p>
                    <a class="btn" title="send" href="?option=edit_gallery">перейти</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="admin-block">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8NAy.png" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>ВООРУЖЕНИЕ</h4>
                    <p>Редактирование раздела <br> "Вооружение"</p>
                    <a class="btn" title="send" href="?option=edit_gallery">перейти</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="admin-block">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2X20.png" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>НАГРАДЫ</h4>
                    <p>Редактирование раздела <br> "Награды"</p>
                    <a class="btn" title="send" href="?option=edit_gallery">перейти</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Чтобы блок не сдвигал другие блоки, задайте ему абсолютное позиционирование.

Answer (score 1):

> При наведении мышью на блок, он увеличивает высоту до 100%.

> ```
> .admin-block:hover { 
>      box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25),
>                  0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
>      height: 100%;
> }
> ```

Comment: Убери height: 100% и она перестанет увеличиваться до 100%. Вроде очевидно?

Comment: Так это не помогает

Comment: z-index пробовали устанавливать?

Comment: @Юрий, там надо кучу стилей переписать, чтоб заработало... Потому что там у родительского элемента стили не годятся.

Comment: а что там не так со стилями родительского блока? все вроде нормально, кроме того что transition дублируется дважды. а чтобы блок не сдвигал другие блоки в .admin-block:hover надо добавить z-index выше и все, тогда переход не будет сдвигать элементы, а будет поверх выдвигаться. И если на то уж пошло то height: auto намного лучше.